# VSTO Outlook: Get the current location of the active Outlook window (inspector or explorer)

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I'm working on a VSTO Outlook Add-in and now I'm facing a particular use case where I need to get the screen location of the current active Outlook window (explorer or inspector). Sure it's not possible to use any Outlook API mechanism, but how can I do it using Windows API functions? Any code snippet will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both [Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer) and [Inspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector) Outlook Object Model objects expose the `Top`/`Left`/`Width`/`Height` properties as well as `WindowState`. There is no need to use Windows API to retrieve the window position.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [GetWindowRect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowrect) function which retrieves the dimensions of the bounding rectangle of the specified window. The dimensions are given in screen coordinates that are relative to the upper-left corner of the screen. For example:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool GetWindowRect(HandleRef hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
     public int Left;        // x position of upper-left corner
     public int Top;         // y position of upper-left corner
     public int Right;       // x position of lower-right corner
     public int Bottom;      // y position of lower-right corner
}

Rectangle myRect = new Rectangle();

private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     RECT rct;

     if(!GetWindowRect(new HandleRef(this, this.Handle), out rct ))
     {
     MessageBox.Show("ERROR");
             return;
     }
     MessageBox.Show( rct.ToString() );

     myRect.X = rct.Left;
     myRect.Y = rct.Top;
     myRect.Width = rct.Right - rct.Left + 1;
     myRect.Height = rct.Bottom - rct.Top + 1;
}
```

Also you may find the [GetWindowPlacement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowplacement) function helpful, the function retrieves the show state and the restored, minimized, and maximized positions of the specified window.